# Coding Challenge

Tags: ruby, algorithm

So, recently I was checking a coding challenge. The problem was quite intriguing so just want to know whether there is a better way to do it in terms of time and space complexity.

Problem: Given a number x where x will be positive number > 0. Find the nearest smallest number with the same digits rearranged in a different order. If it exists so return the smallest number otherwise print "Nearest Smallest Number doesn't exist".

So, below are a few examples

Number: 8563
Output: 8536

Number 7385
output 7358

Number: 3857
Output: 3785

Number: 123
Output: Nearest Smallest Number doesn't exist

```
number = gets.to_i
flag = 1
numbers_array =  number.digits.permutation(Math.log10(number).to_i + 1).sort
numbers_array.each_with_index do |e, index| 
  if e.join.to_i == number
    print numbers_array[index - 1]
    flag = 0
    break
  end
end
if flag == 1
  puts "Nearest Smallest Number not exist"
end
```

Note: The above solution will take more time when the number will be very big

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If this problem is from the internet please provide the URL as interested readers may wish to confirm your explanation. For example, you say, "same number of digits" whereas your example suggests you mean "same digits reordered".

Comment: @CarySwoveland I have added more detail to my problem

Comment: My intuition says there is a better way to do this, which will be significantly faster for larger numbers. Not so much faster for small numbers. Basically it seems you want to swap the first small number from the right, with a larger number to the left of that one. Seems that should produce the nearest smaller permutation.

Comment: @Casper Can you share some code for your approach

Comment: "The problem was quite intriguing" -- The problem is so intriguing that the [C++ standard library has a function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/prev_permutation) for it that you can use [out of the box](https://ideone.com/40YoNn). Perhaps Ruby has, too?

Comment: I may be wrong about my fancy algorithm. Need more coffee. Perhaps someone else solves it in the meantime.

Comment: @MOehm I am not sure whether in ruby there is any function similar to prev_permutation.

Comment: The C++ page I linked to has an example implementation. The [Ruby doc on permutation](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/permutation) shows some code (but it's all Ruby to me) and a web search may lead you to the home of programming-challenge topics, [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lexicographically-previous-permutation-in-c/), which has an implementation. After all, these are programming _challenges_, not programming spoonfeedings.

Comment: @MOehm Thanks for the solution. I will try to implement the same method in ruby

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari :D you do not need to take permutation of all digits. Check my answer

Comment: @Casper Why did you delete your answer

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari I added more test cases and realized it wasn't working properly in all situations, and I didn't have time to figure out the right solution. I was essentially writing a previous permutation generator without knowing it, but there was still some part missing which I could not figure out :( Btw. if you search for the C++ implementation of prev_permutation you will find the source. Could be used to convert to Ruby without too much trouble I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is similar to generate the next permutation of an array.

Let's say that we have a permutation

```
a1, a2, a3 ... an
```

What is the preceding permutation of this?

Observation:
The first permutation (the smallest one) would have this property:

```
a1 <= a2 <= a3 ... <= an
```

And the last permutation would have this property:

```
a1 >= a2 >= a3 ... >= an.
```

From this observation, we could go back and forth from a given permutation easily

Let's iterate from the last to the first element, if we could find a position `k` which:

```
ak , ak + 1, and ak > ak + 1
```

Let's find the largest number from `ak + 1 ... an`, let's call it `ax` which satisfied `ax < ak`, and replace `ax` with `ak`, now what we have is

```
a1, a2, ... ax, [...]
```

For the [...], what we should do is sorting them in descending order. And wallah, we find the answer to the problem.

Example:

```
1, 2, 4, 3 => k = 3, x = 4 -> Ans = 1, 2, 3, 4

1, 2, 5, 5, 3, 4 => k = 4, x = 6 -> Ans = 1, 2, 5, 4, 5, 3
```

Java code:

```
public void prevPermutation(int[]data){
     for(int i = data.length - 2; i >= 0; i--){
         if(data[i] > data[i + 1]){
            int index = i + 1;
            for(int j = i + 2; j < data.length; j++){
                if (data[j] > data[index] && data[j] < data[i]){
                     index = j;
                }
            }
            int tmp = data[i];
            data[i] = data[index];
            data[index] = tmp;
            sortDescending(data, i + 1, data.length);
            break; 
         }
     }

}
public void sortDescending(int[]data, int from, int to){
     int[]copy = Arrays.copyOfRange(data, from, to);
     Arrays.sort(copy);
     for(int i = from; i < to; i++){
          data[i] = copy[to - i - 1];
     }         
}
```

Time complexity: `O (n log n)` with `n` is the number of digit.

Live demo: https://ideone.com/ZLaSa0

Slightly better version:  `O (n)` time complexity
https://ideone.com/RvmymX

Comment: I found same in my answer till finding k & x

Answer (score 2):

check with following,

```
def lowest_digit(n)
    digits, index = n.to_s.chars, nil
    str = digits.reverse
    z = str[1..-1].each_with_index.inject([str[0]]) { |m,(a,i)| m << a; index = i if a > m[-2]; break m if a > m[-2]; m }
    z_num = z.reverse.join
    if digits.reverse == z
      "Nearest Smallest Number not exist"
    else
      digits[0..(-3-index)].join + z.permutation(z.length).to_a.map(&:join).select { |x| x < z_num }.max
    end
end

lowest_digit 32964563245279143273348345
 => "32964563245279143273345843"
```

Comment: Thaks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
def largest_smaller(n)
  rv = recurse(n.digits.reverse)
  return nil if rv.nil?
  rv.join.to_i
end
```

```
def recurse(remaining_digits, unused_digits = remaining_digits)
  first_remaining, *rest_remaining = remaining_digits

  return (unused_digits.first < first_remaining ? unused_digits : nil) if
    rest_remaining.empty?

  a = remaining_digits.select { |d| d <= first_remaining }.sort.reverse
  return nil if a.empty?

  a.each_index do |i|
    j = unused_digits.find_index { |d| d == a[i] }
    rest_unused = (unused_digits.dup.tap { |a| a.delete_at(j) }).sort.reverse
    return [a[i]] + rest_unused if a[i] < first_remaining
    rv = recurse(rest_remaining, rest_unused)
    return [a[i]] + rv unless rv.nil?
  end
  nil
end
```

```
largest_smaller 8563
  #=>           8536
largest_smaller 7385
  #=>           7358
largest_smaller 3857
  #=>           3785
largest_smaller 123
  #=>           nil
largest_smaller 32964563245279143273348345
  #=>           32964563245279143273345843
```

All of these executed in the blink of an eye. I will provide a description of the algorithm later.

Comment: This does not seem to run in the blink of an eye: `print (largest_smaller ((0...50000).map { ('0'..'9').to_a[rand(10)] }.join.to_i)).to_s.length`

Comment: @Cary Swovelend Thanks for the answer